# Retornar o nome do mês como select

Tags: postgresql

Preciso retornar o nome do mês com o comando `select`, sei que com o comando

`Select extract('Month',data)`

Ele me retorna o número do mês em questão, há um modo de trazer o no desse mês.

No caso: 01/01/2018 seria apenas `Janeiro`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PostgreSQL possui embutidos métodos para tradução de strings de tempo, de forma a ser desnecessária a criação de métodos personalizados. Você pode utilizar a função [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html), passando como primeiro parâmetro a data extraída e, como segundo parâmetro, a string `'Month'`.

Isso fará com que seja retornado o nome do mês com a primeira letra em maiúsculo (também há 'MONTH' e 'month', se preferir), de acordo com o parâmetro `lc_time` definido em seu `postgresql.conf`. Para o meu caso, onde `lc_time` é `C`:

```
postgres=# select to_char(current_date, 'Month');
  to_char
-----------
 March
(1 row)
```

Caso queira o nome do mês em outra língua sem ter que alterar o .conf, você pode definir o `lc_time` para sua própria sessão e usar a string `'TMMonth'`. "TM" é sigla para "Translation Mode":

```
postgres=# set lc_time  TO 'pt_BR.UTF-8';
SET
postgres=# select to_char(current_date, 'TMMonth');
 to_char
---------
 Março
(1 row)

postgres=# set lc_time  TO 'fr_FR.UTF-8';
SET
postgres=# select to_char(current_date, 'TMMonth');
 to_char
---------
 Mars
(1 row)

postgres=# set lc_time  TO 'ja_JP.UTF-8';
SET
postgres=# select to_char(current_date, 'TMMonth');
 to_char
---------
 3月
(1 row)
```

Assim, complementando a *query* inicial da sua pergunta, tente com:

```
select to_char(extract('Month',data), 'Month');
```

Ou, se o seu PostgreSQL não estiver em português, use:

```
set lc_time to 'pt_BR.UTF-8';
select to_char(extract('Month',data), 'TMMonth');
```

Comment: essa do `lc_time`  e `TMMonth` não sabia, muito bom! obrigado

Comment: É mesmo mó prático! =) Funciona também pros nomes de dias da semana (TMDay, etc.), conforme documentação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo a seguinte função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.namemonth (
  integer
)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
SELECT Case $1
when 1 then 'Janeiro'
when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
when 3 then 'Março'
when 4 then 'Abril'
when 5 then 'Maio'
when 6 then 'Junho'
when 7 then 'Julho'
when 8 then 'Agosto'
when 9 then 'Setembro'
when 10 then 'Outubro'
when 11 then 'Novembro'
when 12 then 'Dezembro'
else NULL
end
$body$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER
COST 100;
```

Para usar:

```
Select namemonth(extract('Month',data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma outra alternativa:

```
SELECT
   (ARRAY[
          'Janeiro',
          'Fevereiro',
          'Março',
          'Abril',
          'Maio',
          'Junho',
          'Julho',
          'Agosto',
          'Setembro',
          'Outubro',
          'Novembro',
          'Dezembro'])[ EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE '01.01.2018') ];
```